# Multivariate student t distribution as a mixture of distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, mixture-distribution, t-distribution

I would like to derive the likelihood function corresponding to a student t model as a mixture of distribution, but there is one point which is not completely clear to me.

It is usually written that $X=\mu+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{U}{\nu}}}Y$  is a student t distributed variables if U is distributed as a $\chi^{2}$ with $\nu$ degrees of freedom.
But it is not very clear to me if for example $X$ and $Y$ are of dimension $T \times N$, whether $U$ is common or different for every variables, i.e of dimension $T \times 1$ or $T \times N$. Could someone bring light on this ?

Comment: The summary in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution) seems quite clear about this. Does that resolve your question?